# Customizing a FileNotFoundError message in Python

Tags: python, exception, customization, filenotfoundexception

I'm able to capture an exception to change its message. For example:

```py
def parse(val, parse_function, errmsg):
    try:
        return parse_function(val)
    except ValueError as e:
        e.args = (errmsg,) #Overwrites the exception message
        raise e

val = input("Enter a number: ")
try:
    val = parse(val, float, "The input is not a number")
except ValueError as e:
    print(e) #if executed, prints "The input is not a number"
```

But, if I do it with a FileNotFoundException, it doesn't work:

```py
def do_stuff(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename, "r") as file:
            pass
            #do stuff with the file
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        e.args = ("The file doesn't exist",) #Overwrites the exception message
        raise e

try:
    do_stuff("inexistent_file_name")
except FileNotFoundError as e:
    print(e) #Doesn't print "The file doesn't exist", prints "[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'inexistent_file_name'"
```

Why is this? And how can I customize a FileNotFoundException message?

Comment: inside except block use **raise Exception("exception message")**

Comment: But I don't want to:
1. Generate a new exception object, but raise the existing one
2. Raise an Exception object, but a FileNotFoundError

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the `__str__` method of `FileNotFoundError` (which is called in the `print` function) does not simply return the `args`. Instead, `__str__` is composing a custom string from `errno`, `strerror`, and `filename` (probably looks something like that: `f"[Errno {errno}] {strerror}: '{filename}'"`).

Therefore, you may want to tweak `errno`, `strerror`, and `filename` instead of `args` to modify the error message, for example:

```
except FileNotFoundError as e:
    e.strerror = "The file doesn't exist"
    raise e
```

This will print `"[Errno 2] The file doesn't exist: 'inexistent_file_name'"`

Answer (score 0):

```
def do_stuff(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename, "r") as file:
            pass
            #do stuff with the file
    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        e.args = ("The file doesn't exist",) #Overwrites the exception message
        raise e

try:
    do_stuff("inexistent_file_name")
except FileNotFoundError as e:
    print(e.args)
```